# Script for emulating Windows [Win]+[Arrow] keyboard shortcut

Tags: shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running Fedora 14. I would like to (at least partially) emulate the behaviour of Windows when you hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Key</kbd>. That is, I would like it to "snap" to the left/right sides of the screen.

I am not very familiar with Linux/Unix, but here is what I have come up with:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 1680 0
```

for moving the current window to the left/right monitor respectively. This would work fine for my purposes, but for some programs it fails to work if the window is maximized. Does anyone know a good way to do this? I suppose one solution would be to restore the window if it is maximized, move it, then maximize it, but I don't know how to do this either.

Comment: Maximization is handled by the window manager. If you want to have a maximized/restored toggle, look in your window manager. Many unix window managers have commands for horizontal and vertical maximization, but they're often disabled by default because Windows didn't have this feature until recently so it wasn't a familiar concept to many people. What window manager or desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with setting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to toggle window maximization (it was a preset shortcut option), along with the aforementioned implementation of `xdotool`. If you have a more direct/more general solution please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the *exact same* behaviour of Windows's Meta+Left/Right arrow keys in KDE: Go to the same kwin keyboard shortcuts dialog and set the "**Quick Tile Window To the Left/Right**" options.

For Meta+Up i find "Maximize Window" or "Maximize Window Vertically" handy.

It works across multiple monitors and it comes in very handy for placing two applications side by side on the screen.